# Get friends most liked photos from facebook using fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to obtain most liked photos of my friends in 2012. I have made the following query.

```
SELECT pid, caption, aid, owner, link, src_big, src_small, created, modified, like_info 
FROM photo WHERE created > 1325356200 and aid 
IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner
IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()))
ORDER BY like_info.like_count DESC LIMIT 30
```

It is giving me most liked 30 photos in descending order. But when I inspected the photos I could understand that the list is not correct. Some most liked photos of my friends's is not there in list. I inspected the query many times. I couldn't understand what is wrong with this query. Can anyone help me to find out why this query is not giving the desired result?
Any suggestions are most welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to the default LIMIT value of every FQL query (LIMIT 100).

1. Firstly **SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()** query runs and outputs your 100 friends
2. Secondly **SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner IN (..100 Friends...)** query runs and output s100 albums of ur 100 friends.
3. Finally SELECT **pid, caption, aid, owner, link, src_big, src_small, created, modified, like_info 
   FROM photo WHERE created > 1325356200 and aid IN (...100 Aid...) ORDER BY like_info.like_count DESC LIMIT 30** query runs and outputs the result from 100 albums.

Apparently the result is not at all what u wanted. You might try to increase your limit by yourself (say LIMIT 1000) but it never worked for me. The only way of getting accurate result is trying graph API, but it will take very long time for executing, eventually its a dead choice.

The Proof for my answer

Try to run these codes

```
SELECT pid, caption, aid, owner, link, src_big, src_small, created, modified, like_info 
FROM photo WHERE created > 1325356200 and aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner IN
(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() order by rand() ))ORDER BY like_info DESC LIMIT 30
```

I used rand() function to randomize the friends

```
SELECT pid, caption, aid, owner, link, src_big, src_small, created, modified, like_info FROM
photo WHERE created > 1325356200 and aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT 
uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() ) order by rand() ) ORDER BY like_info DESC LIMIT 30
```

Here i used rand() to randomize the albums. You can try to randomize the both queries. Every time u execute these codes it will give very different result and you would notice there are many more pictures with many more likes.

Comment: thanks Felix for your explanation. helped me to understand the issue.