# fql multi query to count photos of a friend

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

is there a way via multi query I can get a count of a friend's public photos?

one to get a list of friends, another to do a facebook eqivilent of a count of /friendid/?fields=photos? I would just like to check if they have at least one public photo for my app.

this way it'll return a json array of the list of friends and a corresponding data set that has a count of their photos.

if there's no easy way of doing this, any suggestions on how would this be done with more than one multi query?

Answer (score 0):

The bellow FQL query will do the trick

```
 SELECT aid, owner, name, photo_count FROM album WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner
 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())) AND photo_count > 0
```

It will result the user id of the friend, album name and count of photos in the specific album.

however the result wont be accurate due to the default LIMIT value of FQL query. To know more check my answer about  [the effect of default limit value in FQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097438/get-friends-most-liked-photos-from-facebook-using-fql/14132797#14132797/)